# How to download/export .txt file in java?

Tags: java

I formed an url in the controller.When I hit that url i need to export a .txt file.As I am new to this concept , I have a doubts ,

1) Do we need to import any jar file to export .txt file as like we add jars for pdf and xls ?

I have tried like below..But i dont get any result by it.I didn't add any jar file ..

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("MyFile.txt", true);
        writer.write("Hello World");
        writer.write("\r\n");   // write new line
        writer.write("Good Bye!");
        writer.close();
```

Comment: you mean you want to download the file right?

Comment: yes..I need to download

Comment: Are you using servlets or pure java??

Comment: using servlets too

Comment: Bhanu if you are using servlets then it will be pretty easy stuff to do.

Comment: Try this out but it is having detail explanation http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-servlet-download-file-example

Comment: Its looking too complicated ... Dont we have an example just to download an empty .txt file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107696/discussion-between-bhanu-and-androidgenx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a couple of projects I've used this utility class from [codejava.net](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/use-httpurlconnection-to-download-file-from-an-http-url)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * A utility that downloads a file from a URL.
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */
public class HttpDownloadUtility {
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;


        /**
         * Downloads a file from a URL
         * @param fileURL HTTP URL of the file to be downloaded
         * @param saveDir path of the directory to save the file
         * @throws IOException
         */
        public static void downloadFile(String fileURL, String saveDir)
                throws IOException {
            URL url = new URL(fileURL);
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

            // always check HTTP response code first
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String fileName = "";
                String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
                String contentType = httpConn.getContentType();
                int contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();

                if (disposition != null) {
                    // extracts file name from header field
                    int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
                    if (index > 0) {
                        fileName = disposition.substring(index + 10,
                                disposition.length() - 1);
                    }
                } else {
                    // extracts file name from URL
                    fileName = fileURL.substring(fileURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                            fileURL.length());
                }

                System.out.println("Content-Type = " + contentType);
                System.out.println("Content-Disposition = " + disposition);
                System.out.println("Content-Length = " + contentLength);
                System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);

                // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
                InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
                String saveFilePath = saveDir + File.separator + fileName;

                // opens an output stream to save into file
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);

                int bytesRead = -1;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();

                System.out.println("File downloaded");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No file to download. Server replied HTTP code: " + responseCode);
            }
            httpConn.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It downloads ..But whe we want to write something into that file, how to do it

Comment: Sir, you just need a FileWriter/PrintWriter combo: FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName) ;
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
...
pw.println();

Comment: I have answered it right based on it can u edit that by adding the access of writing the data into file

Answer (score 2):

The code i have written is just a three lines to download the .txt file.
Thank you all For the help.

I am just posting my answer because just to download a empty file who need for the beginners.

```
Adding HttpServletResponse servletResponse dependency,

OutputStream out = servletResponse.getOutputStream();
String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"Report"+".txt\";");
        servletResponse.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

        // obtains response's output stream
        OutputStream outStream = servletResponse.getOutputStream();

        outStream.close();
```